# Sum three equations

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to compute `x1+x2-x3` based on three equations as defined in equations variable. See below:

```
equations = {-x2+mx1 ==3, -6x1+17x2+2x3==14,-21x1+15x3==3};
ineed = {x1+x2-x3}
```

I tried

```
Solve[ineed /. equations]
```

but it did not work. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
equations = {-x2 + m x1 == 3, -6 x1 + 17 x2 + 2 x3 == 14, -21 x1 + 15 x3 == 3};
ineed = {y == x1 + x2 - x3}
Solve[Eliminate[Join[ineed, equations], {x1, x2, x3}], y]
(*y ->(3 (-26 + 17 m))/(-16 + 85 m)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[x1, x2, x3]

{x1, x2, x3} = {x1, x2, x3} /.
   First@Solve[{
      -x2 + m x1 == 3,
      -6 x1 + 17 x2 + 2 x3 == 14,
      -21 x1 + 15 x3 == 3}, {x1, x2, x3}];

ineed = x1 + x2 - x3;

FullSimplify[ineed]
```

> (78 - 51 m)/(16 - 85 m)

Comment: Can be somewhat improved `Simplify[x1 + x2 + x3 /. 
  Solve[-x2 + m*x1 == 3 && -6 x1 + 17*x2 + 2 x3 == 
     14 && -21*x1 + 15 x3 == 3, {x1, x2, x3}]]`.